# Manera correcta de consumir este servicio SOAP con PHP

Tags: php, webservice, soap

Tengo el siguiente web servicie donde puedo preguntar por datos a una `db`, pero no puedo acceder a los métodos. Nose si estoy declarando mal las credenciales

Aqui mi codigo

```
     try {
    $opts = array(
        'http' => array(
            'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
        )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

    $wsdlUrl = 'http://172.20.2.18:1024/ADInterface/services/ModelADService?wsdl';

    $soapClientOptions = array(
        'stream_context' => $context,
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE);

    $checkVatParameters = array(
        'user'=>'WebService',
        'pass'=>'WebService',
        'lang'=>'es_CL',
        'ClientID'=>'1000000',
        'RoleID'=>'1000014',
        'OrgID'=>'1000000',
        'WarehouseID'=>'1000001',
        'stage'=>'0');

    $modelCrud = array(
        'serviceType' => 'WSBPartner',
        'TableName' => 'XX_WEB_WSBPartner',
        'RecordID' => 0,
        'Filter' => '',
        'Action' => 'Read',
        'DataRow' => array(
               'field' => array(
                   'type' => 'integer',
                   'column' => 'C_BPartner_ID',
                   'lval' => '',
                   'disp' => '',
                   'edit' => '',
                   'error' => '',
                   'errorVal' => '',
                   'val' => 1000643,
               )
           )
      );

    $soapclient = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, $soapClientOptions);

   $result = $soapclient->queryData(array(
      "ModelCRUD" => $modelCrud,
      "ADLoginRequest" => $checkVatParameters
                  )
            );

    print_r($result);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

> Mensaje: **Parameter ModelCRUDRequest does not exist!**

Aqui una foto del webservice funcionando en `SoapUI`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberme explicado bien y agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda. Saludos

pd: He estado investigando sobre info para este tipo de webservice.

https://wiki.idempiere.org/en/Web_Services_First_Steps

https://github.com/the-dusky/idempiere-php-composite-api

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega el error o stacktrace que te devuelve

Comment: Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: @Alfabravo poder acceder a los metodos de ese webservice mediantes las credenciales

Comment: Veo que tienes un request en PHP, luego un ejemplo en SoapUI y una respuesta. No es claro qué es lo que no funciona.

Comment: @Alfabravo El request en php no me funciona, si puedes copia el codigo y ejecutalo

Comment: Antes, tú puedes añadir el error que salga en los logs de apache como lo sugiere @PakLei pues decir "no me funciona" no es una buena descripción del problema.

Comment: @Alfabravo Como puedo ver o activar ese log? en el browser me sale `HTTP ERROR 500`

Comment: Tu servicio - `new nusoap_client` es diferente del que dices que te funciona - `new SoapClient`. Son dos clientes diferentes

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev entonces como deberia ser la estructura para este webservice, yo entendia que llamaba al metodo y aplicaba credenciales al metodo

Comment: No lo sé, @MoteCL. Solamente digo que tu código y el ejemplo que dices que funciona son dos librerías diferentes. Deberías mirar la documentación de **nusoap**, la que estás usando, e informarte sobre la llamada. O si quieres usar la otra, pues lo mismo - hay que ver la documentación.

Comment: El php ¿lo ejecutas desde el mismo servidor del web service? ¿Cuál sistema operativo y Java container usas?

Comment: @Sal desde mi localhost Linux Mint 18 , openjdk version "1.8.0_212"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los webservices de xDempiere tienen wsdl, deberías usarlo y setear el segundo parámetro del constructor del cliente.

`$soapclient = new nusoap_client('http://172.20.2.18:1024/ADInterface/services/ModelADService?wsdl',true);`

Y posteriormente.

```
$soapclient->queryData(array( 'ModelCRUD' => $modelCrud
                            , 'ADLoginRequest' => $checkVatParameters
                            )
                      );
```

Si usas SoapClient, puedes depurar revisando el valor de:
`$soapclient->__getLastRequest()`.

Comment: Intente con  `new SoapClient` y obtengo ese error  `SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://172.20.2.18:1024/ADInterface/services/ModelADService?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://172.20.2.18:1024/ADInterface/services/ModelADService?wsdl"`

Comment: Prueba con el WS básico: `ADInterface/services/ADService?wsdl` y el método `getVersion`.

Comment: Mismo error :/  gracias por tu ayuda realmente no entiendo que sucede

Comment: Parece que no es accesible, en un shell del equipo cliente has un `wget` al wsdl. Deberías poder ver el archivo de definición, si no funciona verifica que el puerto 1024 esté abierto en el servidor.

Comment: Puede acceder al webservice pero obtengo este mensaje `Parameter ModelCRUDRequest does not exist!` edite la pregunta

Comment: Te falta agregarle los parámetros al método `queryData()`.

Comment: Que parámetros son?

Comment: Respuesta actualizada con los parámetros.

Comment: la var `$modelCrud` que es?

Comment: Es donde va el nombre de la tabla y -si aplica- los datos. Checa el lado derecho de SoapUI, así como creaste los valores para usuario, password, etc. debes hacer lo mismo para el modelCRUD.

Comment: Solo me salen estos datos en la foto
   `'serviceType' => 'WSBPartner',
        'TableName' => 'XX_WEB_WSBPartner'`
pero me pide `RecordID`

Comment: Eso depende de cómo registraste el Web Service, en la pestaña de parámetros.

Comment: Actualize mi respuesta pero sigue el mismo error provare con `curl`

Comment: Estas mandando como primer parámetro `ModelCRUDRequest` y como segundo al arreglo, sólo va el arreglo.

Comment: le borre el `ModelCRUDRequest` e igual mismo error.